# Hosting a GTK+3 context inside a Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, gtk3

We have a mature C++ Win32 application that we want to migrate to GTK+. We want to do it incrementally. We would like to initialize GTK+ on a child HWND inside our Win32 application. So, at first, GTK+ would only be used in some regions inside our application.

I could not find any Win32-GTK+ interopability helpers in GTK+.

How can I achieve that? How can I host a GTK+ panel in an existing Win32 application?

Comment: Do you use pure WinApi for GUI?

Comment: No, we have an MFC application.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible. You will need 2 event loops: one for GTK part and one for MFC as you can not just use random *gui toolkit 1* widgets with *gui toolkit 2*. Syncronising these loops, interchanging events is going to be huge, HUGE pain. That's why this migration should be done atomically.